# How to add municipalities to map?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, openstreetmap

I've successfully implemented a map of Denmark using Leaflet. However, I need to show the municipalities in Denmark, and this is surprisingly complicated.

On [this page](https://docs.mapbox.com/data/boundaries/reference/), I gather that there are Mapbox Tileset IDs for administrative boundaries, so I suppose in principle, I could use these tilesets, but I feel this is not adequately explained on this page.

Can tilesets be added to a Leaflet map as a layer? This is unclear. My code for the basic map looks like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([56,12], 7);
    
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 20,
    id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: '[my_access_token]'
}).addTo(map);
```

Just replacing `mapbox/light-v9` with e.g. `mapbox/boundaries-adm4-v3` and the map is gone. Adding an entire new `L.tilelayer(...id('mapbox/boundaries-adm4-v3')...).addTo(map);` gives me the same old map with no administrative boundaries.

Am I naïve in expecting Mapbox to provide me with a free map of the municipalities of Denmark?

Have I combined too many things by using Leaflet, Mapbox *and* OpenStreetMaps?

How do I accomplish what I need? 1. Drawing of the Danish municipality boundaries on the map; 2. Coloring of selected municipalities.

Answer (score 1):

Note that these are ***Vector** Tiles*.

Leaflet has no built-in functionality for rendering these types of tiles. However, you can take a look at the officially documented *Vector-Tiles plugins*: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#vector-tiles

Comment: Ok, so this leads me to the next question: Where does one obtain vector tiles with the Danish municipality boundaries? What's the mine type and filename extension of vector tile files?